# Weak and strong self usage, blocks memory management

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, objective-c-blocks

There are a bunch of questions about all these weak and strong selves but I want that you guys took a look at my particular example:

```
- (void)getItemsWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(NSArray*items))completionHandler {
 __weak __typeof__(self) weakSelf = self;
 [self doWorkWithCompletionHandler:^(Response *response) {
     // this completion is not on main thread
     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         ...
         [weakSelf doAnotherWorkWithCompletionHandler:^(Response *response) {
             // this completions is not on main thread either
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                 __typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
                 NSArray *itemsIds = [strongSelf doWorkOnMainThread1];
                 NSArray *items = [strongSelf doWorkOnMainThread2];
                 completionHandler(items);
             });
         }]; 
     });
 }];
}
```

Is everything correct here or not? Also you are welcome to suggest a refactoring

Comment: This question might be better sorted on [Codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: What's the point of having `itemsIds` and `items` declared in the outer local scope? It's not like that scope will exist by the time those two variables are assigned to in the asynchronous operation.

Comment: What makes you think that you need weak references here?

Comment: The question is mostly about the blocks memory management not refactoring!

Answer (score 1):

If you turn all warnings on, then you will get a warning for

```
[weakSelf doAnotherWorkWithCompletionHandler... ];
```

You shouldn't send messages to weak objects. A weak object could disappear while the method that is called is running. Store the weak object into a strong one, the result is either nil or not. If you then call

```
[strongSelf doAnotherWorkWithCompletionHandler... ];
```

you know that either strongSelf == nil and nothing happens, or strongSelf is and stays not nil while the method is executing.

Answer (score 0):

You should check if completionHandler is not NULL and then call it.

```
if (completionHandler) {
  completionHandler(items);
}
```

Otherwise you'll crash if completionHandler is NULL

---

You may also reconsider if you want to call `completionHandler(items)` at all if `self == nil` at any point. I say that, because there is a slight inconsistency.
In line

```
[weakSelf doAnotherWorkWithCompletionHandler:^(Response *response) {
```

if weakSelf is nil already, then it's `completionHandler` will not be called and in result `completionHandler(items)` will also not be called.

But in here:

```
__typeof__(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
NSArray *itemsIds = [strongSelf doWorkOnMainThread1];
NSArray *items = [strongSelf doWorkOnMainThread2];
completionHandler(items);
```

if `self == nil` then `completionHandler` will in fact be called.

Of course I don't see the whole picture and maybe it's completely irrelevant, but something you might want to take under consideration.

Going further, I assume you'd rather **have** `completionHandler` called in each and every scenario, even if `self == nil` at any point. Or add an error parameter to it in case of anything going wrong.

---

And if you want to be super pedantic, you might want to put __weak after the type, as such:

```
__typeof__(self) __weak weakSelf = self;
```

It's the preferred way: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/objectivec/rn-transitioningtoarc/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011226-CH1-SW4 (look for "You should decorate variables correctly.")